# How do I destroy all these user preferences UI elements?

Tags: interface

I'm new to blender and for some reason when I clicked on "edit user preferences" from the dropdown menu of the wrench in the top left nothing happened, so I dragged the corner near it which  created a new toolbar somehow. I tried to drag that to close it but it made even more toolbars. I kept trying to close them but I only got more and more! Then I was somehow able to get it open as a pane in the main window, and the same thing happened when I tried to slide that one closed! Why is the even possible? Why would anyone ever want more than one? Is this real life? Is this just fantasy?

[image: What even is this, what??]

[image: MS-paint depiction of how blender's UI feels]

Comment: That image made my day! thanks, +1 just for that :) Now good luck closing them all..

Comment: How do I close them though??

Comment: OH! I figured it out. Only a toolbar can truly kill a toolbar... Thank you!

Comment: Flexibility kills flexibility....